# How to speed up PHP Depend

Tags: php, profiling

I'm running [PHP Depend](http://pdepend.org/) on our code base to profile the PHP. It's a large code base, and I have been disappointed by how long it is taking to iterate through all of the files: days.

It's an internal server, but pdepend has sucked up all of the available memory and is constantly swapping. Is there a config setting I can set to get PHP Depend to dump data out of memory? Are there any suggestions on getting this to speed up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might I suggest a profiling tool: [XHProf](http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof) & [XHGui](https://github.com/preinheimer/xhprof). The former is a profiler you can run in production, the latter is a [GUI](http://blog.preinheimer.com/index.php?/archives/355-A-GUI-for-XHProf.html) you can use to visualize the information you've received. Since PHP Depend seems to be written in PHP it would be pretty effective at determining what the code is up to.

Comment: @Aaron since you accepted this answer, can you provide your findings?  I'm running into a similar situation, and would like to know if there's any way to reduce the memory consumption of pdepend.  I see that it takes ~1.4GB of RAM to analyze a codebase of only 1.5MB, and only 150 PHP files. That to me sounds absurd. :(  I don't understand why it takes 1000-times the original file size in memory.

Answer (score 0):

pDepend does scan and analysis on every line of every file of supplied paths. And it does get very slow in bigger code base. Since it runs on command line process, APC cache won't help either. One approach would be divide your code into modules with separate pDepend reports but if you use common library in all modules, reports would not be very accurate.

Latest pDepend has some performance improvements if you are using older one.
http://pdepend.org/news/pdepend-1.0.0-released.html